# How to apply a check that there are no two same name files in main and sub directory in javafx

Tags: filechooser

Basically i am making a program to save user notes in notepad that is .txt format and a user has his folder name with his username and he can also create a sub directory in it . So i want that whenever he saves a file , there is a check applied that for example if he saves with name note1 in main directory then there should be no other file named note 1 in the subdirectory too .

Comment: not related to fx

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
String filename ;
Path directory ;
```

you can do:

```
Optional<Path> matchingFileName = Files.walk(directory)
    .filter(path -> path.endsWith(Paths.get(filename))
    .findAny();

if (matchingFileName.isPresent()) {
    // there's a matching filename in a subdirectory
}
```

Comment: @HarisKhan What do you mean by “enter path and filename”?

Comment: nvm the problem has been resolved . was using stack overflow for the first time for a query , found it truly helpful . thnx Brother.